# How to connect to PostgreSQL in Spring Boot 2 using a Bean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, postgresql-9.3

I would like to connect to PostgreSQL using a bean (@Bean) and Spring Data.

At this bean, I would like to use my own customer properties in application.properties file, like these properties below

```
my.db.user=postgres
my.db.password=root
my.db.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
```

I can't use use default properties (spring.datasource.url , spring.datasource.username, etc .. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot 2 by default uses Hikari to manager connections.

So, you can do it.

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public HikariDataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123456
```

If you wanna use `tomcat-jdbc`, add the following config.

```
spring.datasource.type=org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
```

Reference link : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0.0-M2-Release-Notes#default-connection-pool

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own DataSource with your custom database properties the following way.

```java
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my.db")
public DataSource myDataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

Have a look at the following description to configure two databases for a full example, this explains how you can use your own properties
[two databases example](http://www.devglan.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-multiple-database-configuration)